# How to find the closest word to a vector using BERT

Tags: nlp, word-embedding, bert-language-model

I am trying to get textual representation(or the closest word) of given word embedding using BERT. Basically I am trying to get similar functionality as in gensim:

```
>>> your_word_vector = array([-0.00449447, -0.00310097, 0.02421786, ...], dtype=float32)
>>> model.most_similar(positive=[your_word_vector], topn=1))
```

So far, I have been able to generate contextual word embedding using [bert-as-service](https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service#getting-elmo-like-contextual-word-embedding) but can't figure out how to get closest words to this embedding. I have used pre-trained bert model (uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12) and haven't done any fine tuning.

Answer (score 22):

**TL;DR**

Following the [Jindtrich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59874553/6498293) I implement a context-aware nearest neighbor searcher. The full code is available in my [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/avidale/c6b19687d333655da483421880441950)

It requires a BERT-like model (I use [bert-embeddings](https://pypi.org/project/bert-embedding/)) and a corpus of sentences (I took a small one from [here](https://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/en/download/)), processes each sentence, and stores contextual token embeddings in an efficiently searchable data structure (I use [KDTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html), but feel free to choose FAISS or HNSW or whatever).

**Examples**

The model is constructed as follows:

```
# preparing the model
storage = ContextNeighborStorage(sentences=all_sentences, model=bert)
storage.process_sentences()
storage.build_search_index()
```

Then it can be queried for contextually most similar words, like

```
# querying the model
distances, neighbors, contexts = storage.query(
    query_sent='It is a power bank.', query_word='bank', k=5)
```

In this example, the nearest neighbor would be the word "*bank*" in the sentence "*Finally, there’s a second version of the Duo that incorporates a 2000mAH power **bank**, the Flip Power World.*".

If, however, we look for the same word with another context, like

```
distances, neighbors, contexts = storage.query(
    query_sent='It is an investment bank.', query_word='bank', k=5)
```

then the nearest neighbor will be in the sentence "*The **bank** also was awarded a 5-star, Superior Bauer rating for Dec. 31, 2017, financial data.*"

If we don't want to retrieve the word "bank" or its derivative word, we can filter them out

```
distances, neighbors, contexts = storage.query(
     query_sent='It is an investment bank.', query_word='bank', k=5, filter_same_word=True)
```

and then the nearest neighbor will be the word "*finance*" in the sentence "*Cahal is Vice Chairman of Deloitte UK and Chairman of the Advisory Corporate **Finance** business from 2014 (previously led the business from 2005).*".

**Application in NER**

One of the cool applications of this approach is **interpretable named entity recognition**. We can fill the search index with IOB-labeled examples, and then use retrieved examples to infer the right label for the query word.

For example, the nearest neighbor of "*Bezos announced that its two-day delivery service, **Amazon** Prime, had surpassed 100 million subscribers worldwide.*"  is "*Expanded third-party integration including **Amazon** Alexa, Google Assistant, and IFTTT.*".

But for "*The Atlantic has sufficient wave and tidal energy to carry most of the **Amazon**'s sediments out to sea, thus the river does not form a true delta*" the nearest neighbor is "*And, this year our stories are the work of traveling from **Brazil**’s Iguassu Falls to a chicken farm in Atlanta*".

So if these neighbors were labeled, we could infer that in the first context "Amazon" is an ORGanization, but in the second one it is a LOCation.

**The code**

Here is the class that does this work:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
from tqdm.auto import tqdm


class ContextNeighborStorage:
    def __init__(self, sentences, model):
        self.sentences = sentences
        self.model = model

    def process_sentences(self):
        result = self.model(self.sentences)

        self.sentence_ids = []
        self.token_ids = []
        self.all_tokens = []
        all_embeddings = []
        for i, (toks, embs) in enumerate(tqdm(result)):
            for j, (tok, emb) in enumerate(zip(toks, embs)):
                self.sentence_ids.append(i)
                self.token_ids.append(j)
                self.all_tokens.append(tok)
                all_embeddings.append(emb)
        all_embeddings = np.stack(all_embeddings)
        # we normalize embeddings, so that euclidian distance is equivalent to cosine distance
        self.normed_embeddings = (all_embeddings.T / (all_embeddings**2).sum(axis=1) ** 0.5).T

    def build_search_index(self):
        # this takes some time
        self.indexer = KDTree(self.normed_embeddings)

    def query(self, query_sent, query_word, k=10, filter_same_word=False):
        toks, embs = self.model([query_sent])[0]

        found = False
        for tok, emb in zip(toks, embs):
            if tok == query_word:
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            raise ValueError('The query word {} is not a single token in sentence {}'.format(query_word, toks))
        emb = emb / sum(emb**2)**0.5

        if filter_same_word:
            initial_k = max(k, 100)
        else:
            initial_k = k
        di, idx = self.indexer.query(emb.reshape(1, -1), k=initial_k)
        distances = []
        neighbors = []
        contexts = []
        for i, index in enumerate(idx.ravel()):
            token = self.all_tokens[index]
            if filter_same_word and (query_word in token or token in query_word):
                continue
            distances.append(di.ravel()[i])
            neighbors.append(token)
            contexts.append(self.sentences[self.sentence_ids[index]])
            if len(distances) == k:
                break
        return distances, neighbors, contexts
```

Comment: This is a superb answer

Answer (score 11):

BERT provides contextual representation, i.e., a joint representation of *a word and the context*. Unlike non-contextual embeddings, it is not as clear what the closest word should mean.

A good approximation of close words is certainly the prediction that BERT does as a (masked) language model. It basically says what similar words could be in the same context. However, this is not in the [client API of bert-as-service](https://bert-as-service.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/client.html#module-client). You can either implement the prediction layer yourself (I think it is just multiplication of the last layer with the embedding matrix + softmax, but maybe there is some additional projection going on) or use a different implementation such as [Hugginface's Transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers).

The most theoretically correct (and computationally expensive) solution would be running BERT on a large dataset and store pairs of words and corresponding contextual representations and then use e.g., [faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) for retrieving nearest neighbors that would include also the context, similarly as in the [nearest neighbors language models](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.00172).