# How to add and return the indexes correctly for BERT model

Tags: python

I am using example codes from [examples codes from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59865719/how-to-find-the-closest-word-to-a-vector-using-bert) to apply to my data. The only change I m making is to add a "date column and converting the final output to a data frame. we first changed the example function codes only at this part to include the indexes into storage.query.

```
di, idx = self.indexer.query(emb.reshape(1, -1), k=initial_k)
      
        distances = []
        neighbors = []
        contexts = []
        indexes=[] ### change here
     
        for i, index in enumerate(idx.ravel()):
              token = self.all_tokens[index]
              if filter_same_word and (query_word in token or token in query_word): 
                 continue
              distances.append(di.ravel()[i])
              neighbors.append(token)
              contexts.append(self.sentences[self.sentence_ids[index]])
              indexes.append(self.sentences.index(self.sentence_ids[index])) ## change here
              if len(distances) == k:
                 break
              
        return distances, neighbors, contexts, **indexes**
```

When I run the following codes:

```
distances, neighbors, contexts,indexes = storage.query(query_sent='It is an investment bank.', query_word='bank', k=5)
dd = []
date = df["date"]].values.tolist()
for d, w, c , idx in zip(distances, neighbors, contexts,indexes):
    dd.append(
     {'date':date[idx],
       'neigh' : w,
        'score':d,
       'para' : c.strip()})
ad =pd.DataFrame(dd)
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: Try adding `print(date[idx], idx)` into the for loop to better understand the problem. Also, `print(len(date))`

Comment: Thanks, print(len(date)) = 500, and  print(len(indexes)) = 50, and print(len(contexts)) = 50. it seems that the change function codes is not correct. Now after changing as indexes=[], and in the end  indexes.append(self.sentences.index(self.sentence_ids[index])). It still does not work.  Now the error is ValueError: 319 is not in list. Do you hve any other suggestion please.

Comment: You don't seem to be filling `sentence_ids` with anything

Comment: Thanks Mike!!. Can you please explain a bit. I could not quite get it.